# How to parse time using a specific timezone

Tags: go, time, timezone

I am to get a time struct from a string. I am using the function `time.ParseTime()` with the layout `"2006-01-02 15:04"`.

When I execute the function with any valid time string I get a time struct pointing to that time stamp but it is in UTC.

How can I change it to a different time zone? To be clear I want the same timestamp but with a different time zone. I don't want to convert between timezones; I just want to get the same time object but not in UTC.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseInLocation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`time.ParseInLocation`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseInLocation) to parse time in a given [Location](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Location) when there's no time zone given. `time.Local` is your local time zone, pass that in as your Location.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // This will honor the given time zone.
    // 2012-07-09 05:02:00 +0000 CEST
    const formWithZone = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
    t, _ := time.ParseInLocation(formWithZone, "Jul 9, 2012 at 5:02am (CEST)", time.Local)
    fmt.Println(t)

    // Lacking a time zone, it will use your local time zone.
    // Mine is PDT: 2012-07-09 05:02:00 -0700 PDT
    const formWithoutZone = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm"
    t, _ = time.ParseInLocation(formWithoutZone, "Jul 9, 2012 at 5:02am", time.Local)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: not sure if abbreviations like CEST give the correct UTC offset on all systems. You could also [set a specific location](https://play.golang.org/p/3YtSVOh6LI_H).